Sequence contains more than one error [ANOMALY]
Link Query:
        var previousAudit = DbContext.AuditInspections
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Where(i => i.CreationDateTime >= financialYearStart.AddYears(-1) &&
                    i.CreationDateTime <= financialYearStart.AddDays(-1) &&
                    i.SiteModelId == inspectionData.SiteId &&
                    i.FlowStateModel.Name == StateEnums.AuditReportReleased)
        .OrderByDescending(i => i.CreationDateTime)
        .Select(i => new
        {
            i.Id,
            i.AuditDateTime,
            i.DeadlineDateTime,
            Score = i.AuditInspectionQuestionModels
                .GroupBy(q => new
                {
                    q.AuditQuestionPriority,
                    q.AuditChoice
                })
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    g.Key.AuditQuestionPriority,
                    g.Key.AuditChoice,
                    Count = g.Count()
                })
                .ToList()
        })
        .FirstOrDefault();

SQL Generated:
SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[AuditDateTime], [t].[DeadlineDateTime], [t].[Id0], [t0].[AuditQuestionPriority], [t0].[AuditChoice], [t0].[Count]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(1) [a].[Id], [a].[AuditDateTime], [a].[DeadlineDateTime], [f].[Id] AS [Id0], [a].[CreationDateTime]
    FROM [AuditInspections] AS [a]
    INNER JOIN [FlowStates] AS [f] ON [a].[FlowStateModelId] = [f].[Id]
    WHERE [a].[CreationDateTime] >= @__AddYears_0 AND [a].[CreationDateTime] <= @__AddDays_1 AND [a].[SiteModelId] = @__inspectionData_SiteId_2 AND [f].[Name] = N'Audit Report Released'
    ORDER BY [a].[CreationDateTime] DESC
) AS [t]
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT [a0].[AuditQuestionPriority], [a0].[AuditChoice], COUNT(*) AS [Count]
    FROM [AuditInspectionQuestions] AS [a0]
    WHERE [t].[Id] = [a0].[AuditInspectionModelId]
    GROUP BY [a0].[AuditQuestionPriority], [a0].[AuditChoice]
) AS [t0]
ORDER BY [t].[CreationDateTime] DESC, [t].[Id], [t].[Id0], [t0].[AuditQuestionPriority]

Error:

An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element.
at async Task Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync(IAsyncEnumerable asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken) x 2
at async Task ios_api.Controllers.Features.AuditModule.Inspection.AuditInspectionController.ShareAuditInspectionReports(int inspectionId, ReportRecipients reportRecipients) in C:/Usera/Project/msTest/ios_api/Controllers/Features/AuditModule/Inspection/AuditInspectionController.cs:line 2986

When I convert the linq query to IEnumerable<>, the error is resolved:
            var previousAudit = DbContext.AuditInspections
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(i => i.CreationDateTime >= financialYearStart.AddYears(-1) &&
                        i.CreationDateTime <= financialYearStart.AddDays(-1) &&
                        i.SiteModelId == inspectionData.SiteId &&
                        i.FlowStateModel.Name == StateEnums.AuditReportReleased)
            .OrderByDescending(i => i.CreationDateTime)
            .Include(auditInspectionModel => auditInspectionModel.AuditInspectionQuestionModels)
            .ToList()
            .Select(i => new
            {
                i.Id,
                i.AuditDateTime,
                i.DeadlineDateTime,
                Score = i.AuditInspectionQuestionModels
                    .GroupBy(q => new
                    {
                        q.AuditQuestionPriority,
                        q.AuditChoice
                    })
                    .Select(g => new
                    {
                        g.Key.AuditQuestionPriority,
                        g.Key.AuditChoice,
                        Count = g.Count()
                    })
                    .ToList()
            })
            .FirstOrDefault();

or
simply just removing line:5 of the linq query, also eliminates the error:

i.SiteModelId == inspectionData.SiteId &&

inspectionData.SiteId is an int value and not a List<T>, that I am sure of.
Can anyone explain why I am getting this error?
I am using .net 8.0

what type is inspectionData?

@fubo It is of anonymous type:
var inspectionData = await DbContext.AuditInspections     .AsNoTracking()     .Where(r => r.Id == inspectionId)     .Select(i => new     {         SiteId = i.SiteModelId,     })     .SingleOrDefaultAsync(); 

Why don't you add that to the question? That's where you have SingleOrDefaultAsync and that's where the exception occurs.

@GertArnold through debugging, it is clear that the error occurred on the linq mentioned in the question. So shouldn't the error occur while defining inspectionData if the problem was in inspectionData?

The issue relates the SingleOrDefaultAsync() method. This method returns the only element of a sequence that satisfies a specified condition or a default value if no such element exists and this method throws an exception if there is more than one element in the sequence.
You can try to use the FirstOrDefaultAsync method, it will return the first element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence contains no elements. Or using your workaround (convert the linq query to IEnumerable<>).
